# inotifywait - Only restarting ghci on every second save

Tags: bash, haskell, ghci, inotify, inotifywait

## The Script

I have a short bash script that uses `inotifywait` to restart a `ghci` repl on a given file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

$(while inotifywait -e close_write $1; do pkill ghc; done) &

while inotifywait -e close_write $1
do 
    sleep 2
    stack ghci $1    
done
```

## Explanation

This line:

```sh
$(while inotifywait -e close_write $1; do pkill ghc; done) &
```

takes care of stopping `ghc` whenever the file is saved.

This section:

```sh
while inotifywait -e close_write $1
do 
    sleep 2
    stack ghci $1    
done
```

takes care of starting `ghc` whenever the file is saved (after a 2 second delay).

## Trying it out

Given the following Haskell file loaded in vscode:

```hs
abc = 123
```

launch the script as follows in a terminal window:

```sh
$ ./inotifywait-stack-ghci.sh abc.hs
```

If you save the file twice (see issue below) the repl should restart.

## The issue

The script pretty much works! There's one issue however: the repl only reloads on every second file save. So basically, to get the repl to reload, I have to save the file twice.

Has anyone seen this sort of thing before? Any suggestions for resolving it?

## Notes

- I've tagged this post with `inotify`, but also with `haskell` in case the issue is somehow idiosyncratic to `ghci`.
- The script works well when the file is edited in vscode. Vim and Emacs don't seem to work well with it due to how they save their files.
- The script works under the assumption that you only have one copy of `ghc` running at a time.
- I've been testing this in Ubuntu 20.04.2 under WSL.

Comment: Have you ever seen [ghcid](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid)? It's a very nice little program, similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AriFordsham, yup! Folks on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/orgjz2/automatically_reloading_ghci_when_a_file_changes/) suggested that. However, it seems that `ghcid` doesn't run a repl, which the above script aims to do.